# Closing Angular2 modal on click outside the modal

Tags: angular, onclick

This is the Sample code to have click outside to disable the selection. In this example I am able to deselect but only after I click on the element to activate the listener. I want to use this example to close the modal on click outside of the modal anytime. Any example would be appreciated.

```
activeIndex = 0;

subscription: any;
init$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
stop$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  let click$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');

const clickOutside$ = this.init$.flatMap(() => {
  return click$.takeUntil(this.stop$);
});

this.subscription = clickOutside$.subscribe(() => {
  this.activeIndex = null;
  console.log(1);
  this.stop$.next();
});
}

onItemClicked(event, index: number) {
event.stopPropagation()
this.activeIndex = index;
this.init$.next()
}

ngOnDestroy() {
if(this.subscription) {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lx9eBU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

So I have an example of how I handled closing a custom dropdown that I created but I believe it will work for this as well.

So inside of your component:

```
openModal() { document.addEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this)); }

offClickHandler(event:any) {
    if (!event.target.closest(".select-options") && !event.target.closest(".select-input")) { 
        // do whatever you want here
        // close the modal
        // call document.removeEventListener
    }
}
```

So that will look for a click outside of button and div, but for you I would just set the .closest() to the modal you want to see closed. Then inside the if statement close your modal.

Comment: Hey joshsisley I tried this but it wont stop listening to the click events. I want to stop listening to the events once the modal is closed. It does work but not exactly as I wanted. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Gotcha, one other thing that could work then would be to add the event listener when the modal is opened and then close it inside of the if statement when closing the popup.

Comment: how to close it. I was trying document.removeEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this));

Comment: yeah you would want to remove it by doing the document.removeEventListener('click',this.offClickHandler.bind(this));

Comment: I edited the answer also to only add the event listener when the button is clicked to open the modal, that way it isn't always listening and only listening when the modal is open

Comment: ` ngAfterViewInit() {     document.addEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this));
    console.log('Listener removed'); }
offClickHandler(event: any) {
    console.log('Entered new experiment');
    if (!event.target.closest('.modal-body') && !event.target.closest('.modal-body')) {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.offClickHandler.bind(this));
      
       this.closeModal();
    }
  }    `

Comment: hey joshsisley can you give me the exact code to remove the listener. It wont stop listening

Comment: The only thing is that you wouldn't need both of those event.target.closest('.modal-body') in the IF statement. So it would just be if (!event.target.closest('.modal-body')) {}

Comment: Also right now you have the event listener being added in the ngAfterViewInit function. This would make it listen every time the view is reinitialized. I would take it out of there and put it in the function used to open your modal